# Euler/RK4 python for Orbite simulation

Tags: python, runge-kutta

I started a code for an orbite simulation for 8 planetes (with the sun in (0,0))
I got accelerations on X and Y, now I need to use them to get the speed on X and Y, using Euler first, then RK4, and I got stuck, I don't know where to start. Here's my code:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself, using proper formatting, not as a screenshot. See [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/113848) for more information.

Comment: Also, for the minimal example, reduce the body count to 3, this should still show all problems without including to much non-essential data/code.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually use vector arithmetic as provided by `numpy`.

You should unify the way you construct the parameter arrays. There is no obvious reason to differentiate between position and velocity. Perhaps even dedicate a procedure `add_body(m,x,y,vx,vy)` that extends the lists.

> Your acceleration computation went wrong, you started writing code to compute the acceleration for one body but switched to computing the list of accelerations for all bodies producing a mismatch of parameters. You should have gotten divide-by-zero errors.

The Euler method will produce qualitative errors very fast, do not be discouraged by that.